# File wont move to folder vbs

Tags: vbscript, directory, move

So im writing a script that drops a file folder then moves that file to the folder it dropped it self. Well the folder drops fine but the file wont move. Can some see whats wrong with my code? Or give me a better way to move the file. I also get no error message about trying to move the file.

```
Dim folder,fso,filsys,C    
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemObject")    
Set folder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(1)    
Set wshshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")    
Set filesys = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")    
Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemObject")  
Set c = fso.GetFile(Wscript.scriptFullname)

On Error Resume NEXT

Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\55egr932ntn7mk23n124kv1053bmoss5")
If Err.Number<>0 Then 
End If

WScript.Sleep 3000
C.Move ("C:\552ntn7mk23n124kv1053bmoss5\File.exe") (folder&"\File.exe")
```

And I have a program I use that turns the VBS into and EXE so you see the "file.exe" which really is the .VBS itself

Comment: I'd get rid of the On Error Resume Next, or at least turn error trapping off after you use it (On Error Goto 0, I think). That should give you an error message that might help you debug this.

Comment: So The error go it got was on line 12 and it says the path was not found.

Comment: The first two things I'd do (after fixing the formatting so that you have an idea of what's happening) is remove the `On Error Resume Next` and the empty `If Err.Number<>0 Then End If` block, so you can get some kind of indication of what's going wrong. It's easier to identify errors if you pull your head out of the sand and pay attention to them, instead of hiding them all and then wondering why it's not working. You get no error message because you've deliberately hidden all of the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this syntax, but the line below looks like it's expecting the `folder` variable to be a string.

```
C.Move ("C:\552ntn7mk23n124kv1053bmoss5\File.exe") (folder&"\File.exe")
```

Earlier in code it looks as though you're setting `folder` as an object.

```
Set folder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(1)
```

You might not get the error you mentioned in your comment if you convert `folder` to a string.

~~

Another thing to try is the following code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(1)
Alert (folder&"\File.exe")
```

(I'm not sure if it's "Alert" or "Msgbox" or something else.) That test will show you whether the file path makes sense. If you get an error on line 3 of that test, try converting `folder` to a string before your Alert (or Msgbox).

Comment: Hmm Well I did what you said and it came out to be "c:\windows\system32\File.exe" But the file is on the desktop.

Comment: Well that's the folder that the code is going to try to use. If you want a different file path, you may need to hard-code it instead of using `fso.GetSpecialFolder(1)`. But whatever path you use, make sure it exists, and make sure your script will have read/write access to it.

Comment: I had another thought. Maybe you get the error on line 12 in your original code because `C:\552ntn7mk23n124kv1053bmoss5\File.exe` doesn't exist. Your code creates the folder, but does it put `File.exe` in there? If not, you'll get an error for sure.